# gdal_translate GeoTIFF to NetCDF: values

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I have a GeoTIFF file of sea ice concentration.

When I use gdal_info it gives a series of values like:

> Metadata:
>       COLORINTERP=Palette   Color Table (RGB with 65536 entries)
>       0: 9,60,112,255
>
> ```
> 1: 9,60,112,255
>
> 2: 9,60,112,255
>
> 3: 9,60,112,255
>
> 4: 9,60,112,255
>
> 5: 9,60,112,255
>
> 6: 9,60,112,255
>
> 7: 9,60,112,255
>
> 8: 9,60,112,255
>
> 9: 9,60,112,255
> ```

When I use gdal_translate to convert to netcdf:

gdal_translate -of netCDF test.tif test.nc

and I look at the values in the test.nc file I get:

> ...
>
> 3662500 4187500 2540
>
> 3687500 4187500 2540
>
> 3712500 4187500 2540
>
> 3737500 4187500 2540
>
> -3837500 4212500 0
>
> -3812500 4212500 0
>
> -1712500 4212500 16
>
> -1687500 4212500 0
>
> -1612500 4212500 36
>
> -1587500 4212500 48
>
> ...

My question is: When `gdal_translate` converts to NetCDF, what does the value in the third column represent?
Points that are equal to 2540 seem to be land cells, while points with 0 value are ocean cells.

Are points with value ranging from 0 to 1000 (where sea ice concentration exists) in per thousands? (i.e 100 = 10% sea ice concentration, 1000 = 100%?)

File test.tif: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dru7nygzglyh9hd/test.tif?dl=0

File test.nc: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nidn1rz38na5np5/test.nc?dl=0

Comment: Can you tell us where you acquired the data in the first place? There might be some helpful tips in the documentation.

Comment: Hello, this is a sea ice concentration file from the NSIDC Index 3 datase: https://nsidc.org/data/G02135/versions/3

Comment: In the 'User's guide' tab of the link above, the monthly sea ice concentration images are detailed on pages 7-8